# ConstraintLayout - constraintHeight_percent gets ignored when view above another view?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

]I'm using constraint layout in version 1.1.0 beta 6 (Which is way better than the stable 1.0.2 by the way...)

However, using constraintHeight_percent doesn't work for me in some case.

Here's what I want to achieve:

1. Place a button(bottom-button) with a fixed height at the bottom of the constraint layout
2. Place another button(top-button) between the top of the constraint layout, and above bottom-button.
3. Make the top-button final height to be half of its height.

Here's the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:background="#71B9DE">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bottomButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:text="BOTTOM BUTTON"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="TOP BUTTON - The height should be 75dp!!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here's the preview:

[image]

And here's how I expected it to be:

[image]

I don't understand why after using **app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.5"**, the height of the top button is still 150DP and not 75DP.

It seems like **app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.5"** calculation is done related to the parent height, and not related to the button height itself, after it got constrained.

Btw, I'm not looking for other solutions (Using guidelines, barriers). I really try to figure out why it doesn't work.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: @NileshRathod I expected that the top view will be firstly placed between the constraint layout top, and the bottom button. And then will get shorter by half height (150DP / 2 -> 75DP), thanks to app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.5".

Comment: can u share any  screen shot for the same

Comment: @NileshRathod I added screenshot

Comment: have you tested it with wrap_content for height instead of 0?.

Comment: @UmarHussain 0dp means MATCH_CONSTRAINT. wrap_content will break the constraints, and in this case will only.. wrap content

Answer (score 3):

According to [official reference document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html) in the section '*MATCH_CONSTRAINT dimensions (Added in 1.1)*':

> layout_constraintWidth_percent and layout_constraintHeight_percent : will set the size of this dimension as a percentage of the parent

provided that the corresponding constraints are set to `MATCH_CONSTRAINT` (`0dp`)

Answer (score -2):

You shoud use android:layout_width="match_parent" instead of 0dp

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I don't understand how the WIDTH related to the issue? Besides, match parent breaks whole the constraints idea. Needless to say that it doesn't help